# Facebook Send method fetching wrong content?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, fb.ui

I am using facebook send method for invite friends in my website.

this is the code

```
function FacebookInviteFriends()
  {
    FB.ui({
      method: 'send',
      name: 'Join Stuffuneed',
      picture: '<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/owl_logo_250_250.jpg') ?>',
      link: '<?php echo $customerLink?>',
      description: "You have been invited to join Stuffuneed. Stuffuneed is the place to find the stuff you always needed but didn't know where to find",
    });
  }
```

it's showing me this dialog

[image]

problem is this
it's not showing me exact name.picture,link description.

i have also use og meta tags

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Join Stuffuneed" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.stuffuneed.com/stuffuneed/skin/frontend/default/lockrez/images/owl_logo_25_250.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Stuffuneed"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.stuffuneed.com/stuffuneed/"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
```

but it's still showing me wrong content
Pls help me...

Comment: Is the image/link hosted on any live server? Or on the localhost?

Answer (score 0):

`description` `picture` are not the valid parameters in the **send** dialog. [Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/)

You'll just have to provide the link; and fb will fetch the image by itself. May be you can set the meta tag of `og:image` in the link you have provided.

Comment: i have also use og meta tags

<meta property="og:title" content="Join Stuffuneed" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.stuffuneed.com/stuffuneed/skin/frontend/default/lockrez/images/owl_logo_25_250.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Stuffuneed"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.stuffuneed.com/stuffuneed/"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>

but still showing wrong content

Comment: Is facebook recognizing your meta tags? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: yes but sometimes it gives me 
Could not retrieve data from URL.

my url is : http://www.stuffuneed.com/stuffuneed